# Stop alarm manager after 10 times

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

setRepeating method keep on repeating alarm but I would like to stop after 10 times where should i close this .

below code is repeating my alarm

```
         alarammanager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                1000 * 60 * 30, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: you can take one static variable as alarmCounter and increase it by one everytime , and on 10 stop to set repeating alarm

Answer (score 0):

First, you initialize a variable to count the number of times. Everytime your alarm repeat, increase it (+1) until this variable equal to 10, See this following:

Call cancel() on AlarmManager with an equivalent PendingIntent to the one you used with setRepeating()

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AlarmReceive.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.cancel(pi);
```

Comment: Thanks for your responces.I did not get what your saying exactly.Do you mean writhe this                    for(int inc=0;inc<10;inc++)  {   alarammanager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                1000 * 60 * 30, pendingIntent);
    }

Comment: Nope, please read this article carefully for example: http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android

You create a static variale, and count up (increment by 1) this variable in onReceive() method, also check this variable if it equal to 10 then call a method to cancel your alarm (this method is declared in the class where you start your alarm)

Answer (score 0):

In shared preferences, initialize an integer with value 0.
In the notification receiver class, increment the value. If value is equal to 10, cancel the alarm otherwise store the updated value in Shared preferences